# Unable to obtain JDBC connection from datasource

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, gradle

I was trying to run the following command in gradle and it gave me the following error :

```
    c:\gsoc\mifosx\mifosng-provider>gradle migrateTenantListDB -PdbName=mifosplatfor
m-tenants
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8005
:migrateTenantListDB FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\gsoc\mifosx\mifosng-provider\build.gradle' line: 357

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
> Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.843 secs
```

The script file is here and the line no. of error is shown as 357 but I dont know why it is showing me an error. Is it something about incorrect configuration in mysql server please help me out here:
script:

```
task migrateTenantListDB<<{
    description="Migrates a Tenant List DB. Optionally can pass dbName. Defaults to 'mifosplatform-tenants' (Example: -PdbName=someDBname)"

    def filePath = "filesystem:$projectDir" + System.properties['file.separator'] + '..' + System.properties['file.separator'] + 'mifosng-db' + System.properties['file.separator'] + 'migrations/list_db'
    def tenantsDbName = 'mifosplatform-tenants';
    if (rootProject.hasProperty("dbName")) {
        tenantsDbName = rootProject.getProperty("dbName")
    }

    flyway.url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$tenantsDbName"
    flyway.locations= [filePath]

    flywayMigrate.execute()
}
```

Comment: I have never used gradle, but I would recommend that you recompile with --stacktrace, just like the error message recommends, so that you can get a hint as to why things didn't compile.  I also recommend you point out exactly which line is lien 357, to help people start looking.

Comment: Instead of invoking the task directly, try setting the task type to flyway migrate and configuring upfront. You may have forgotten to put the mysql driver on the classpath so the plugin can't load it

Answer (score 0):

The gradle script for this project has got mysql password hard-coded to mysql. You need to set your localhost password to mysql and check the connection before trying this command.